# Tkinter how to update second combobox automatically according this combobox

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I have encountered an issue with combobox updates in Tkinter Python.

I have two comboboxes:

- combobox `A` with `values =['A','B','C']` and
- combobox `B`

What i want is that:

- when value `A` is selected in combobox `A` then in combobox `B` show the values `['1','2','3']`
- when value `B` is selected in combobox `A` then in combobox `B` show the values `['11','12','13']`
- when value `C` is selected in combobox `A` then in combobox `B` show the value s `['111','112','113']`

Currently part of my code as follows:

```
def CallHotel(*args):
    global ListB
    if hotel.get()==ListA[0]
        ListB=ListB1
    if hotel.get()==ListA[1]
        ListB=ListB2
    if hotel.get()==ListA[2]
        ListB=ListB3

ListA=['A','B','C']

ListB1=['1','2','3']

ListB2=['11','12','13']

ListB3=['111','112','113']

ListB=ListB1

hotel = StringVar()
hotel.set('SBT')

comboboxA=ttk.Combobox(win0,textvariable=hotel,values=ListA,width=8)
comboboxA.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",CallHotel)
comboboxA.pack(side='left')  

stp = StringVar()
stp.set('STP')

comboboxB=ttk.Combobox(win0,textvariable=stp,values=ListB,width=15)
comboboxB.pack(side='left')
```

Comment: What is the problem ? Do you get error message ? Show it in question.

Answer (score 6):

Actually you don't need the global variable `ListB`.  And you need to add `comboboxB.config(values=...)` at the end of `CallHotel()` to set the options of `comboboxB`:

```
def CallHotel(*args):
    sel = hotel.get()
    if sel == ListA[0]:
        ListB = ListB1
    elif sel == ListA[1]:
        ListB = ListB2
    elif sel == ListA[2]:
        ListB = ListB3
    comboboxB.config(values=ListB)
```

And change the initial values of `comboboxB` to `ListB1` directly:

```
comboboxB=ttk.Combobox(win0,textvariable=stp,values=ListB1,width=15)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it do not show any error, it just not update the list as my expect.

Comment: and now, i use the config function, so it resolved the issue.